# Valor Inicial Sequences Postgresql - Laravel 5.1

Tags: php, banco-de-dados, laravel, postgresql, laravel-5

Bom dia, estou realizando alguns testes na minha aplicação, mas estou com o seguinte problema: Após o `migrate` e o `db:seed`, sempre que eu vou inserir algum registro pela aplicação da um erro de chave primária duplicada. Já vi que esse erro é devido ao `increment` continuar em 1 mesmo após inserir dados com o `db:seed`. Teria alguma forma de eu definir esse valor manualmente de forma automática, sem ter que ir de tabela em tabela e mudando?

Seed:

```
 public function run()
    {
        Model::unguard();

        App\Models\Admin\Profissao::create(['id'                       => '1', 
            'titulo'                => 'Engenheiro(a)',
        ]);

        App\Models\Admin\Profissao::create(['id'                       => '2', 
            'titulo'                => 'Tecnólogo(a)',
        ]);

        Model::reguard();
    }
```

Migration:

```
public function up()
{
    Schema::create('profissoes', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->engine = 'InnoDB';
        $table->increments('id');
        $table->string('titulo', 16);
        $table->longText('descricao')->nullable();
        $table->timestamps();
    });
}
```

Comment: o ideal é você deixar a tabela em branco e realizar o seed, ja tentou isso?

Comment: Poste seu seed e sua migration. Você está definindo a coluna no banco como Serial? Seu seed está definindo valores para a coluna ID manualmente?

Comment: Como assim? O que eu faço é rodar o migrate para criação das tabelas, então já vai ta tudo em branco, não? E depois eu rodo o seed, mas o seed não altera o increment la nos sequences.

Comment: Postado @MarcoAurélioDeleu

Comment: Remova a especificação da coluna id da sua seeder e verifique se o problema some. Isto é, coloque apenas a coluna titulo na seeder.

Comment: ok, vou ver aqui.

Comment: Era isso mesmo @MarcoAurélioDeleu. Não imaginava mesmo que pudesse ser isso... Muito obrigado!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

O problema está na sua Seeder:

```
 public function run()
 {
    Model::unguard();
    App\Models\Admin\Profissao::create(['titulo' => 'Engenheiro(a)']);
    App\Models\Admin\Profissao::create(['titulo' => 'Tecnólogo(a)']);
    Model::reguard();
}
```

Dessa forma, você não especificará o valor da coluna ID manualmente.

O problema é que, diferente do MySQL, o PostgreSQL utiliza sequências. Essas sequências são estruturas separadas da tabela. No MySQL, ao inserir um registro com a coluna ID definida, a tabela automaticamente passará para o próximo valor quando for auto-incrementar. Já no PostgreSQL, a estrutura `sequence` não tem conhecimento que o valor foi inserido porque você não usou a sequencia.

Uma vez que você não especifica o valor, o Laravel vai utilizar a sequência por você e ela automaticamente será incrementada.